# Create Word documents based on cell values throws Subscript error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a copy of a Word file using the value of each cell in a range as the file name. The file name is each Monday of the year.

I'm getting an

> Error 9: Subscript out of Range

The path and filename are valid. Should I approach this task a different way?

```vb
Sub batch_minutesbuilder()
    On Error GoTo errHndl
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'word declaration
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.document
    Dim sel As Word.Selection

    'set the excel workbook and worksheets
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("MinutesTemplate")

    Dim fso As Object
    'Dim fld As Folder
    Dim sourcePath As String, destPath As String
    Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, row As Range
        
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2", "D53")
    Set rng = ws.Range("D2:D53").Value
    
    'Uncomment for testing
    MsgBox rng
    
    sourcePath = "C:\SLC\"
    
    'Uncomment for testing
    MsgBox sourcePath
    
    destPath = "C:\SLC\"
    
    'Uncomment for testing
    MsgBox destPath
    
    sourceFile = "MinTemplate.docx"
    
    'Uncomment for testing
    MsgBox sourceFile
    
    destFile = ""    
 
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        sourceExtension = VBA.Split(VBA.Trim(row.Cells(, 2)), ".")(1)
        MsgBox sourceExtension
        sourceFile = sourcePath & "MinTemplate.docx"
        MsgBox sourceFile
        
        destFile = destPath & VBA.Trim(row.Cells(, 1)) & "." & sourceExtension
        MsgBox destFile
        
        fso.CopyFile sourceFile, destFile, False
    Next row
    
    MsgBox "Yay! Operation was successful.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done"
    Exit Sub
 
errHndl:
    MsgBox "Error happened while working on: " + vbCrLf + _
    sourceFile + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error " + _
    Str(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("MinutesTemplate")

Comment: This error happens when the sheet name doesn't exist in the workbook. Check for misspellings

Comment: I thought the issue was the sheet name also: I've tried renaming to something simple like shname and the error continues.

Comment: Are you sure you're working with the right Workbook? the line `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` gets the workbook of the macro. Try this `MsgBox wb.Name` to see if the workbook is the same or `Dim sh As String
    
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In wb.Worksheets
        sh = sh & vbCrLf & s.Name
    Next
    MsgBox sh` to see all the worksheets names